# Loading Component Template from Database or File

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-ivy, angular-compiler

Is it possible to compile an HTML template from a database or .html file in real-time? An example use case would be storing Blog Article HTML in a database and loading dynamically into a component.

Use [innerHTML] will NOT work if the template contains Angular components - as they will not render.

Is it possible to use Compiler (deprecated) alongside Ivy / AoT compilation? I have seen some examples of using compileModuleAsync() to do something along these lines - but is it possible or recommended w/ Ivy AoT compilation?

Thanks

Tried to use [innerHTML] - but Angular components do not render.